# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected (keras Sequence model layer) to have n dimensions, but got array with shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I have loaded images to train my model on recognizing one feature in those images.

- Xtrain is a numpy ndarray of shape `(1380,200,200,3 )` containing 1380 images sized 200 by 200pixels in RGB format
- Ytrain has targets. shape (1380,2)

  [image: shape and model layers]

When I train my model (`model.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)`)  I seem to get a value error on everyone of the layers. As if the input was both `Xtrain` then `Ytrain`...

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected `batch_normalization_24` to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape `(1380, 2)`

Image:

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of Keras's batch normalizer layer's output is the same as its input. Since you have only two labels, your final layer in a Sequential model should generate two outputs. You can consider adding a `Dense` layer like:

```py
model.add(Dense(2), activation='relu')
```

I also recommend to check your model's architecture using `print(model.summary())` and make sure that inputs and outputs match with your dataset and vice versa.